# why click events or gestures are not work in carousel page childs on IOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Im trying to click Image,box or label object which in Carousel views content page. Android works fine but IOS not, why? Can you help or explain?

Here is simple demo:

```
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
          x:Class="CarouselPageNavigation.MainPage">
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="0,40,0,0" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Green" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Color="Green" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
            </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
        </BoxView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is .cs

```
        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("sdada", "sdada", "sdadada");
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10162

Comment: @Jason thanks man.

Comment: Hi , now this issue has been fixed , you can update Xamrin Forms to the latest version 4.5.0.617 , then it will work in iOS 13.4 .

Comment: Hi i solved it update to beta IOS SDK update on mac side before xamarin.forms 4.5.0.617. It was worked too, thanks for answer.

Comment: @SametSığırcı Glad find the solution , remember to share in answer to mark it . Then other people will know that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I solved it update to beta IOS SDK update on mac side before xamarin.forms 4.5.0.617.
>
> Now this issue has been fixed , you can update Xamrin Forms to the latest version 4.5.0.617 , then it will work in iOS 13.4 .

Thanks Junior Jiang